# prove that the induced map $f : H^{2}/{\sim}\to\ S^{2}/{\sim}$ is a homeomorphism.

Tags: general-topology

Let $H^2$ be the closed upper hemisphere in the unit sphere $S^2$ and let $i: H^2 → S^2$ be the inclusion map.

prove that the induced map $f : H^2/{\sim}\to\ S^2/{\sim}$ is a homeomorphism.

Please can you explain the solution clearly? I wonder the solution way of that problem so much. Thank you.

Comment: and what is the equivalence that you mod out by? Presumably you want to show that $H^2/\sim$ is homeomorphic to $ S^2$? and not $S^2/ \sim$?

Comment: I guess, $\sim$ is generated by $x\sim -x$ as $S^2$ is embedded to the unit ball around origin in $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: @berci please can you solve it clearly?

Comment: The question should be edited to explain what the relation is in the denominator in $H^2/{\sim}$.

Comment: @MichaelHardy thereisahomeo-morphism
$RP^{2} ≃ S^{2}/{antipodal points} = S^{2}/∼$

Comment: Note on notation: H^2/\sim\to S^2/\sim looks different from H^2/{\sim}\to S^2/{\sim}.  In the former, the spacing before and after \sim is that which is appropriate when \sim is a binary relation with something before and after it, as in $a\sim b$.  Observe: $H^2/\sim\to S^2/\sim$ versus $H^2/{\sim}\to S^2/{\sim}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If indeed $\sim$ is the relation $x \sim -x$ then what you need to do is this: Consider the composition (which I call $F$)

$$F : H^2 \hookrightarrow S^2 \longrightarrow S^2/{\sim}$$

and consider the map $\pi : H^2 \to H^2/\sim$. Then because $F$ is constant on the fibres of $\pi$ the universal property of the quotient topology means that we get a unique continuous map

$$\overline{F} : H^2/{\sim} \longrightarrow S^2/{\sim}$$

which is surjective since $F$ is. To see that $F$ is surjective notice that for any $[x] \in S^2/{\sim}$, $[x] = F(x)$ if $x \in H^2$; otherwise $[x] = F(-x)$ if $x$ is in the southern hemisphere.

Furthermore it is clear that $\overline{F}$ is injective. Thus we have a continuous bijection $\overline{F}$ between a compact space and a Hausdorff space. Hence $\overline{F}$ is a homeomorphism.

**Proof that $S^2/{\sim}$ is Hausdorff:** Choose $[x],[y] \in S^2/{\sim}$ such that $[x] \neq [y]$. Then back in $S^2$ we have $x \neq y$ and $x \neq \pm y$. Since $S^2$ is Hausdorff we can choose $U_x$ about $x$ and $U_y$ about $y$ such that $U_x \cap U_y = \emptyset$. The canonical quotient $\pi : S^2 \to S^2/{\sim}$ is an open map and so $\pi(U_x)$ and $ \pi(U_y)$ are two disjoint open sets about $[x]$ and $[y]$, proving that $S^2/{\sim} $ is Hausdorff.

**Exercise:** Prove that the canonical quotient map $\pi : S^2 \to S^2/{\sim}$ that sends $x$ to its equivalence class is an ***[open map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_and_closed_maps)***.

Comment: thereisahomeo- morphism
$RP^{2} ≃ S^{2}/{antipodal points} = S^{2}/∼ $

Comment: @B11 That is what I have in my answer.